# How to create tables that spill into the next page in ConTeXt?

Tags: tables, context

I have a table like this in ConTeXt, per a workplace template, with borders around every cell.

```
\startsetups table:all
    \setupTABLE[align={hyphenated, normal}]
    \setupTABLE[frame=on]
\stopsetups
\startsetups table:three
    \setupTABLE[column][1][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right, distance=0.05\textwidth]
    \setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right]
    \setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right]
\stopsetups

\starttext
    \startTABLE[setups={table:all, table:three}]
        \NC column 1 \NC column 2 \NC \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth \input knuth  \NC\NR
    \stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

The data in each column is very long, so unfortunately, the data disappears off the bottom of the page.

I tried `split=yes`, but that splits the table, not the middle of cells. Huge cells still run off the bottom of the page.

How can I get the table cells to be split in half so that the data continues onto the next page?

Comment: That is not possible.  Tables can only be split at cell boundaries, the cell content is unbreakable.  Furthermore, your MWE does not reproduce the issue but only sets some completely unrelated options.

Comment: I've updated the MWE so it has the issue. If not via tables, is there some way to pretend it is tables (e.g. put boxes around columns so it looks like tables)?

Comment: Actually `tabulate` can split the cell content across pages, see the linked duplicate for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fake larger cells using `leftframe, rightframe, topframe, bottomframe` options.

If you have full control over the input, you can split up the longer entries by paragraph or any other natural division. This would look something like:

```
\usemodule[visual]

\startsetups table:all
    \setupTABLE[align={hyphenated, normal}]
    \setupTABLE[frame=off]
    \setupTABLE[split=yes]
\stopsetups
\startsetups table:three
    \setupTABLE[column][1][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right, distance=0.05\textwidth]
    \setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right]
    \setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.333\textwidth, align=right]
\stopsetups

\define\filler{\fakenwords{30}{5}}

\starttext
    \setupTABLE[r][1,4][leftframe=on, topframe=on, rightframe=on]
    \setupTABLE[r][2,5][leftframe=on, rightframe=on]
    \setupTABLE[r][3,6][leftframe=on, bottomframe=on, rightframe=on]
    \startTABLE[setups={table:all, table:three}]
       \NC column 1 \NC column 2 \NC \filler \NC\NR
       \NC  \NC \NC \filler \NC\NR
       \NC  \NC \NC \filler \NC\NR
       \NC column 1 \NC column 2 \NC \filler \NC\NR
       \NC  \NC \NC \filler \NC\NR
       \NC  \NC \NC \filler \NC\NR
    \stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

If you are using `csv` input, then it might be possible to parse the input in lua to split up longer entries according to a specified pattern and then generate a list of "top", "middle", and "bottom" cell numbers to input into `setupTABLE[r][...]`. But this would depend on your specific needs.